# Can only upload the first image each time my camera takes a picture

Tags: python, image, camera, upload, capture

I've setup my RPi, motion detector and camera to capture an image whenever motion is detected. Each time an image is captured, I'd like to automatically upload that image to Google Drive (and delete it from my RPi).

Everything seems to be working with one exception - my script captures and uploads the first image to Google Drive with no problems but then it continues to upload that same image and only that image each time the camera is subsequently triggered. The subsequent images are being captured and stored on my RPi properly, just not uploaded to Google Drive.

I'm only a couple weeks into coding so please have mercy on me (and sincere thanks for any help). Relevant bits below:

```
class MotionUploader:
    def __init__(self, config_file_path):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(config_file_path)

def upload_snapshot(self, snapshot_file_path):
        """Upload a snapshot to the specified folder. Remove duplicates."""
        folder_id = self._get_folder_id(self.snapshot_folder)
        file_name = os.path.basename(snapshot_file_path)
        media = MediaFileUpload(snapshot_file_path, mimetype='image/jpeg')
        self.drive_service.files().insert(media_body=media, body={'title':file_name, 'parents':[{u'id': folder_id}]}).execute()          


while True:
   i=GPIO.input(11)
   if i==0:    #When output from motion sensor is LOW
      print "All quiet... too quiet...",i
      GPIO.output(3, 0) #Turn OFF LED
      time.sleep(3)
   elif i==1:     #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
      print "!Achtung!",i
      GPIO.output(3, 1) #Turn ON LED
      now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")  
      camera.rotation = 180
      camera.start_preview()
      camera.capture("/home/pi/motion-uploader/Photos/"+ now + ".jpg")
      cfg_path = sys.argv[1]
      vid_path = sys.argv[2]  
      MotionUploader(cfg_path).upload_snapshot(vid_path)        
      camera.stop_preview()
      time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: The path for ``camera.capture(...)`` changes, but you always pass the same path to ``upload_snapshot(...)``.

Comment: Thanks Mike. So in my infinite noobdom, I'm struggling to figure out how to write a path for upload_snapshot that matches the camera.capture path. If I simply repeat "("/home/pi/motion-uploader/Photos/"+ now + ".jpg") for upload_snapshot I get a syntax error.

Comment: My friend got it working with the following: `photo_filename = "/home/pi/motion-uploader/Photos/%s.jpg" % now
      photo_file = open(photo_filename, "wb")
      camera.capture(photo_file)
      photo_file.close()

      cfg_path = sys.argv[1]
      vid_path = sys.argv[2]  
      MotionUploader(cfg_path).upload_snapshot(photo_filename)`